# Flutter stack widget transition

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
Stack(
    children: [

      RedWidget(),

      GreenWidget(),

    ],);
```

[image: Ques image]

The transition between these two widgets is explained in the image.

The widgets should not move.
The red widget should appear in place of green while scrolling

1. is there an implicit animation for this?
2. any transition methods?
3. any pub.dev package?
4. only solution is to build it from scratch.?(is building from scratch worth it, in terms of performance on iOS and Web(Canvas)?

Comment: So, when the user scrolls, the green widget's height should be reduced and then fixed at top and the red should be scrollable. Like this?

Comment: no, the widgets themselves do not change in any way, not in dimensions, nor should they scroll, the visible part of the widgets is where while scrolling the green should disappear, and from the same line, red should start appearing, it is like they are changing their position in the stack along with the scroll. when scrolling is complete the green widget essentially becomes the first widget in the stack(hidden behind the red widget ).@LalitFauzdar